# Database association, Case model has two People

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I got a case model. This case model has a client and an opponent field.
 Both of them are Person models. A case has exactly one client and one opponent. Now a Person can be a client or it could be an opponent and a Person can have many cases.
How can i build this association in rails? When i split the Person model into a client and an opponent model it seems quite easy, but that does not seems very dry to me.

This is what i have at the moment

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases 
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :opponent, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

This works so far, that i can add clients and opponents to a case.
But how can i find all the cases through a client or an opponent?

---old
when i have Client.first.cases my sql query is:
--new
of course i mean Person.first.cases-- since i dont have a clients table, just my id inside the Case table is called client_id or opponent_id

SELECT `cases`.* FROM `cases` WHERE `cases`.`person_id` = 3

Now this has to be the client id or the opponent id

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(~ last 10 minutes of) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhFK0UO9VPs ~  
Here is almost the explanation of my problem with a Person model and a Message model, where the Message Model has a receiver_id and a sender_id.
 The foreign key is not needed at the Case model (to go back to my question), it is needed inside the Person model like this

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cases, foreign_key: "client_id"
end
```

so on a Person object i can use not `person.cases` and i will get all the cases, where this person is the client.
I still don't know, how to get the cases, where the person is the opponent

Answer (score 0):

When you asks for `Client.first.cases`, In this query Active Record understand, you want all cases to be fetched that belongs to Person table's first record (which id is 3). 
`person_id` is `client_id`, because first client's id in your person table is 3.

If you will write : `Client.first`, In your sql query you will see :

```
SELECT person.* FROM person WHERE person_id = 3
```

I think, you should try to pass a foreign_key constraint in you `Case` model like this:

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: "client_id"
  belongs_to :opponent, class_name: 'Person',foreign_key: "opponent_id"
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mean Clients.first.cases, i meant Person.first.cases

Comment: Updated my answer, It should help.

Comment: not sure if i am missing something, but i sill cant find all cases for a person. Do i have to make my own query? e.g. something like Person.first.client_cases or Person.first.opponent_cases ?